# Getting issue when install composer Laravel 7 Image Intervention

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to install  Laravel 7 Image Intervention using following command

```
        composer require intervention/image
```

but while installing i am getting three errors belows

```
       1) PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes 
         exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

```
        2)Check 
          https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory- 
           limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

        3)Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted 
          (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

I dont know why this happen? If anyone have idea then please let me know.
Please help me in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try put `memory_limit = -1`

at php.ini on your local server

Comment: into php/ folder i have two php.ini files first is php.ini-development and second is php.ini-production. Exact whic file i need to change?

Comment: there is no file  with name php.ini ?